# Is it possible to run batch scripts from Azure against an on-premise server?

Tags: azure, batch-file, azure-data-factory

I need to run various batch scripts on an on-premises Windows server. These scripts need to be called from an Azure service. We were thinking of using Datafactory to orchestrate the whole process but we are looking for a way to call these scripts.

Would it be possible using Azure Functions? Is it possible to connect somehow with the on-premises Windows machine and call the scripts in a secure way?

Comment: Why? Powershell has functions to handle azzure cmdline, so why go with the old when the new is so much simpler.

Comment: Hello Gerhard, thanks for your help. Could you share with me which functions you are referring to? Also, how can I orchestrate the call of these PowerShell functions from Azure?

Comment: Basics [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/get-started-azureps?view=azps-5.8.0) and you'd maybe find some more interesting stuff [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-hybrid-powershell) as well.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Aleix, very thanks for Gerhard's helps. I help him summarize the comments as the answer. Can you think about accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you. If you have any other update, it's great useful if you can share with us.